# How specify the way to pronounce number/amount of money with TwiML?

Tags: twilio, voice, twilio-twiml

I'm using amount of money without any dollar sign ([because Twilio doesn't work with all currency's codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25823652/twiml-pronunciation-of-the-currency-voice)) and the big amount is pronounced not like should. For example "1212.77 Canadian dollars" isn't sounded like "one thousand and two hundred ...", it's "twelve, twelve point seventy seven ...".
Is there some way to generate multicurrency amount of money with Twilio text-to-speech engine?

**Updated**
Problem with amount of money is just alice voice engine problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you will find you answer here,

http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/say#hints

Here is a snippet stating the problem.
•When saying numbers, '12345' will be spoken as "twelve thousand three hundred forty-five." Whereas '1 2 3 4 5' will be spoken as "one two three four five."

so the simply solution for you might be just to add a space between your numbers.

You could also create yourself a helper, that you divide you values and instead of asking Twilio to read back 1212.77, you would write 1000 200 12 point 7 7, you could get quite creative with such a helper and this would leave you very much in control of how your values are pronounced and also perhaps what spacing / pauses you would like in between certain values. you could then have your helper write something like 1000 200 and 12 dollars and 77 cents. you could make use of your programming language globalisation helpers to get the names for the currency in question and also the minor parts such as dollars and cents or rupee and paise.

I hope this helps.